# Building Complicated If-Statement

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three `if` statements which they are apparently working on different functions. I wanted to combine them into one function, thus I have to combine the `if` statement. But I was stuck at how to use the `||` `&&` and `()`.

My functions as filters, user can fill in whichever textboxes. On button click event, the code will find those that met criteria. Three of them work well independently, but combining them is very tough. Please bear with me and help me, I am just a very new programmer and no background at all. I am stuck for days. ;(

My filters snapshot:

[image: Filters]

First:

```
if (itemAuthor.ToLower() == txtComAuthor.Text.ToString().ToLower())
```

Second:

```
if ((!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out startDate)
      || DateTime.Parse(itemDate, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal) >= startDate) &&
      (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out endDate)
      || DateTime.Parse(itemDate, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal) <= endDate))
```

Third:

```
if (txtComKeyword1.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()) ||
    txtComKeyword2.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword2.Text.ToLower()) ||
    txtComKeyword3.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword3.Text.ToLower()) ||
    txtComKeyword4.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword4.Text.ToLower()))
```

Comment: Before I work any further, is there a reason for combining the if statements?  They might be more maintainable if you keep them in seperate lines.

Comment: In your new `if` statement, are you trying to test if the first, second and third conditions are all `true` or if only one of them is `true`?

Comment: @Doc I don't know. :( because I have only one button to click and on click event it will search all the XML files I have, then return those that met the criteria (eg. author, or relevant date, or keywords or combination of author name + keyword1 + start date).

Comment: @DFord any of them is filled up then the result will show only those met the criteria like I explained to Doc. it sounds very crazy :(

Comment: @Shyuan It sounds like you don't want to combined them into one if statement. I sounds like you want to keep each if statement and if each one evaluates to true, do something, such as use that text box in a search. Is this right?

Comment: I have to question how wise it is to actually do this.  Why don't you just use bool method.  You really should clean up your code.  I can't give stand trying to "fix" your code because there are so many things functionaly wrong with it.

Comment: that is why i seek for help and then i learnt about bool method from the below answer. I just started programming one month ago and never had any experience and people start voting down my question. if i am capable of doing it, i wouldn't have to ask.

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 4):

Whether to use || or && depends on whether you want the meaning *at least one condition is true* (use ||) or *all conditions must be true* (use &&).

If you need to mix both meanings, use () to cause conditions to be evaluated against each other, e.g.

```
if ( (a && b) || (c && d))
```

means if *both a and b are true* **or** *both c and d are true*.

It makes for easier-to-read and maintain code if you define separate booleans for each portion of the compound logic.  There is no performance difference.

```
bool condition1 = !DateTime.TryParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out startDate);
bool condition2 = DateTime.Parse(itemDate, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal) >= startDate);
bool condition3 = !DateTime.TryParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out endDate);
bool condition4 = DateTime.Parse(itemDate, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal) <= endDate);

if ((condition1
      || condition2 &&
      (condition3
      || condition4)
```

Comment: I do believe I've been ninja'd.

Comment: But I will have lots of conditions and at the end the if statement will be very long as well, am i correct or wrong? :|

Comment: @Shyuan Actually, no.  If statements are actually just bool comparisons (statements looking for true or false.)  In this case, you're just saving the trues and falses for later, then comparing the results.

Comment: This is semantically correct, but will become a maintenance nightmare later. Each of these things is a different type of filtering. If we were trying to be elegant, we'd propose LINQ, but that's too much overhead right now. Rather than encourage complicated expression logic inlined, I'd break this up further.

Answer (score 2):

It will help you understand if you break each one of these clauses into functions and divvy up the complexity accordingly. Smaller pieces are easier to work with, and more maintainable in the long run. When you evolve as a programmer, you will eventually not use if statements for this at all, but rather leverage the power of polymorphism.

For now, begin by piecing things apart.

```
public void btnAnalyze_onClick(){
    List<Item> results = new ArrayList<Item>();
    if(txtComAuthor.Text != String.Empty)
    { 
       List<Item> matched = filterByAuthor(txtComAuthor.Text);
       results.addRange(matched);
    }
    if(txtComStartDate.Text != String.Empty)
    {
       List<Item> matched = filterByStartDate(txtComStartDate.Text);
       results.addRange(matched);
    }
    // do the same for the others
    return results;
}



public List<Item> filterByAuthor(String desiredAuthorName){
      List<Item> matches = new ArrayList<Item>();
      //have your data access piece here, from DB/Excel/whatever.
      List<Item> candidates = ...
      foreach(Item candidate in candidates){
         if(candidate.ToLower() == desiredAuthorName){ 
            matches.add(candidate)
         }
       }
       return matches;
}
```

Experienced programmers will realize that there's a lot of duplication here and will have fits at the violations of DRY and performance. That's ok. It can be refactored. For a novice, this will be the easiest style to understand.

If you follow this style, it should be readily apparent where you need to do the filtering. Basically, you will need to replace the if statement in the foreach loop with the condition for the text field you're thinking about.

But you shouldn't need to add a bunch of clauses together doing this because you've broken things apart a little better. If you still find you need a few nested ifs, break it down further into even smaller functions.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about logical grouping, put parentheses around every pair of operations. That way you know how the pairs will be combined.

`if ((A && B) || (C && D))` will evaluate the `(A && B)` and `(C && D)` segments, then "or" those intermediate results together to produce the final value.

For further reading, search for commutative, associative, and distributive properties of boolean logic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you want to evaluate all 3 at the same time, but simply adding them into one big line will be hard to read or maintain.  I'd recommend setting seperate bool values for each of your previous ifs:

```
bool firstIf = (itemAuthor.ToLower() == txtComAuthor.Text.ToString().ToLower());
```

Then comparing all 3 in one statement:

```
if (firstIf && secondIf && thirdif)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It works!");
}
```

This way, it is easier to make changes later if need be, and you can still read the code.